# Set Column to current month in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to set a column called tmonth to say "This months is 'current month', for example:

tmonth
This month is May
This month is May
This month is May
This month is May

I am trying to do this from a stored priocedure. However, the pricedure generates the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'month'.
```

Here is the code:

```
USE [db1]
GO
07:37:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DECLARE @import1 VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @DATE_AP dateTime
DECLARE @month_AP varchar(max)
DECLARE @year_AP varchar(max)

SET @DATE_AP= DATEADD(year, 0, GETDATE())
SET @year_AP = YEAR(@DATE_AP)
SET @month_AP = DATENAME(Month, @DATE_AP)

SELECT CAST(@month_AP as VARchar(10))

print 'this month is'+''+@month_AP+''

SELECT @import22= 'UPDATE [dbo].[table1] SET tmonth='+'This month is'+''+@month_AP+''

EXEC (@import1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this line:

```
 SELECT @import22= 'UPDATE [dbo].[table1] SET tmonth='+'This month is'+''+@month_AP+''
```

to line:

```
 SELECT @import22 = 'UPDATE [dbo].[table1] SET tmonth='''+'This month is'+''+@month_AP+''''
```

becouse the update should look like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[table1] SET tmonth='This month isMay'
```

not this:

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[table1] SET tmonth=This month isMay
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for this to use dynamic SQL. Just the use the variable directly.
Try something like this:

```
USE [db1]
GO

DECLARE @month_AP VARCHAR(100) = 'January';

UPDATE [dbo].[table1] 
SET tmonth = 'This month is ' + @month_AP;
```

Comment: `DECLARE @month_AP VARCHAR(100) = Datename(Month, Dateadd(year, 0, Getdate()))`

Comment: The OP knows the exact value he needs. This is to just point him in the right direction.

Comment: This wont work guys. I did say I need the current month. Dynamic SQL is needed.